# not able to connect to remote mariaDB

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mariadb

I am not able to connect to remote `mariaDB`. Below is my simple `jdbc` connectivity code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.sql.*;
public class Test {
    private static Connection con = null;
    static {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");  
            con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://[some_remote_IP]:3306/billing","root","core@1234");  
        }catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(con!=null) {
            System.out.println("conn established");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("connection failed");
        }
    }
}
```

I am repeatedly getting below exception:

```
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:526)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:513)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:505)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:479)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:1779)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:1596)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:633)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:347)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:219)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.wpits.utilss.Test.<clinit>(Test.java:9)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 73
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.Buffer.readInteger(Buffer.java:271)
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.MysqlaCapabilities.setInitialHandshakePacket(MysqlaCapabilities.java:62)
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.MysqlaProtocol.readServerCapabilities(MysqlaProtocol.java:482)
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.MysqlaProtocol.beforeHandshake(MysqlaProtocol.java:367)
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.MysqlaProtocol.connect(MysqlaProtocol.java:1412)
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.MysqlaSession.connect(MysqlaSession.java:132)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:1726)
    ... 7 more
connection failed
```

remote `mariadb` version is : 5.5.65-MariaDB
and for connectivity, I am using downloaded JAR from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mariadb.jdbc/mariadb-java-client/2.2.3

where is the issue?

Comment: Have you tried modifying connection string with `jdbc:mariadb:...` ? Or with other driver version?

Comment: Given the classes used in the exception stacktrace, right now you're connecting using MySQL Connector/J, and not the MariaDB driver. As WoAiNii suggest, use `jdbc:mariadb:...` instead of `jdbc:mysql:...`.

Comment: @WoAiNii yes I have even tried with `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`

Comment: You are already using the `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`, that is what is what is throwing the exception. To use the MariaDB driver, you need to use the `jdbc:mariadb:` protocol prefix.